# Create a new column by comparing set of column values

Tags: mysql

How can I group a set rows by 'product_id' from a table and create a new column by comparing a set of column values within the group ?

For example,

```
product id   part_id  availability
1            1        true
1            2        false
1            3        true
2            1        true
2            4        true
2            8        true
```

By comparing the 'availability',I would like to create a 'feasibility' column.
If single part is missing it would't be feasible.

```
product_id  feasibility
1           false
2           true
```

I used GROUP BY clause to sort'em out by product_id but I can't figure out the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution available, if you are only interested in the two columns shown in your question:

```
select product_id, min(availability) feasible
from tbl group by product_id
```

See here for a little demo:. http://rextester.com/GMT80394

Answer (score 1):

```
--insert into test(product_id, availability) values (1,true),(1,false),(2,true),(2,true);

select distinct product_id 
from test
where product_id not in (
    select product_id
    from test
    group by product_id, availability
    having availability=false
)
```

Comment: The qualify of this answer we be greatly improved if you explained your code.

Comment: It's quite simple. First of all we get all the products which have availability equal to false `select product_id from test group by product_id, availability having 
 vailability=false`. After that we just select all products who are not in the first list.

Answer (score 0):

use sub-query and `case when` clause

```
    select t.productid,case when availability ='true' 
    then 'product available' else 'product not available' end as feasibility 
   from 
    (
        select  productid,availability from your_table
        group by  productid,availability
    ) as t
```