# Spark aggregation / group by so as to determine a new column's value based on col value in a set

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data that will be grouped by id.

```
id, field
0       A
0       B
0       C

1       B
1       B
1       C

2       E
```

1. I want to group by ID and calculate a simple new value, `is_special`, which is `group by id, if any(field) is in a special set {A, E}` (just a random set of letters, no pattern).

```
id, is_special
0         True 
1        False
2         True
```

Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468021/create-a-new-column-by-comparing-set-of-column-values) but in pyspark.

2. I want to understand how to do this group by without actually grouping, and just create a new column:

```
id, field, is_special
0       A,       True
0       B,       True
0       C,       True

1       B,      False
1       B,      False
1       C,      False

2       E,       True
```

I think it can be done using some of the following, but I don't know how to use a `window` with the `when`.

```
from F import when, col, coalesce

special = ['A', 'E']
window = Window.partitionBy('product_ari')

df.withColumn("is_special", 
    when(col("field").isin(special), lit(True))
)
```

Comment: why the window? what is the question then?

Comment: Good question I have to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test set creation :

```py
a = [
    (0, "A"),
    (0, "B"),
    (0, "C"),
    (1, "B"),
    (1, "B"),
    (1, "C"),
    (2, "E"),
]

b = ["id", "field"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

set_ = ("A", "E")
```

Sevaral ways of doing that.

1. With a join

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

agg_df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "is_special", F.when(F.expr(f"field in {set_}"), True).otherwise(False)
    )
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(F.max("is_special").alias("is_special"))
)
df.join(agg_df, on="id", how="left").show()

+---+-----+----------+
| id|field|is_special|
+---+-----+----------+
|  0|    A|      true|
|  0|    B|      true|
|  0|    C|      true|
|  1|    B|     false|
|  1|    B|     false|
|  1|    C|     false|
|  2|    E|      true|
+---+-----+----------+
```

2. With a window

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.withColumn(
    "is_special", F.when(F.expr(f"field in {set_}"), True).otherwise(False)
).withColumn("is_special", F.max("is_special").over(Window.partitionBy("id"))).show()

# OR "one-liner" 

df.withColumn(
    "is_special",
    F.max(F.when(F.expr(f"field in {set_}"), True).otherwise(False)).over(
        Window.partitionBy("id")
    ),
).show()

+---+-----+----------+
| id|field|is_special|
+---+-----+----------+
|  0|    A|      true|
|  0|    B|      true|
|  0|    C|      true|
|  1|    B|     false|
|  1|    B|     false|
|  1|    C|     false|
|  2|    E|      true|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

For a little bit of intellectual carry-on the following works as well:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    array_intersect,
    size,
    array_except,
    collect_set,
    lit,
    array,
    explode,
)

df = sc.parallelize(
    [
        (0, "A"),
        (0, "B"),
        (0, "C"),
        (1, "B"),
        (1, "B"),
        (1, "C"),
        (2, "A"),
        (2, "E"),
        (2, "A"),
        (2, "A"),
        (2, "G"),
        (2, "J"),
        (3, "A"),
        (4, "E"),
        (5, "A"),
        (5, "E"),
        (6, "Z"),
    ]
).toDF(["id", "field"])
df2 = df.groupby("id").agg(collect_set("field").alias("X"))
df3a = df2.filter(size(array_intersect(df2["X"], lit(array(lit("E"), lit("A"))))) >= 1)
df3b = df2.filter(size(array_intersect(df2["X"], lit(array(lit("E"), lit("A"))))) == 0)
df4 = (
    df3a.select(df3a.id, explode(df3a.X).alias("field"))
    .withColumn("is_special", lit(True))
    .union(
        df3b.select(df3b.id, explode(df3b.X).alias("field")).withColumn(
            "is_special", lit(False)
        )
    )
)
df4.show()
```

returns:

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id|field|is_special|
+---+-----+----------+
|  0|    C|      true|
|  0|    B|      true|
|  0|    A|      true|
|  5|    E|      true|
|  5|    A|      true|
|  3|    A|      true|
|  2|    J|      true|
|  2|    E|      true|
|  2|    G|      true|
|  2|    A|      true|
|  4|    E|      true|
|  6|    Z|     false|
|  1|    C|     false|
|  1|    B|     false|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Comment: @Steven  may be u can appreciate the answer